Is there a closed form for the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(z)z^{\lambda - 1}\exp\left(-\frac{w}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}z$?
As the title says, I would like to know if there is a closed form for the integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(z)z^{\lambda - 1}\exp\left(-\frac{w}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}
I am particularly interested in references on the subject.

Use the known integral representation
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{\lambda - 1}\exp\left(-\frac{w}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}z
=2 K_{-\lambda}(w)$$
of the modified Bessel function of the second kind, differentiate with respect to $\lambda$, to arrive at the desired
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(z)z^{\lambda - 1}\exp\left(-\frac{w}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}z
=2 \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}K_{-\lambda}(w).$$
